# Transformar dados de frequencia absoluta em frequencia relativa no ggplot

Tags: r

```
Mycbon 
Date    Time    Receiver    Transmitter ID    Sensor.Value Sensor.Unit    Station Name    Longitude   Latitude
2019-04-29  05:31:33    134321  4828    #MB06   28.7       °C             PRN               102          121
2019-04-29  08:52:08    134325  4830    #MB06   4.2         m             MVW               102          178
2019-04-29  08:53:13    134325  4831    #MB02   28.6       °C             MVW               150          178
29/04/2019  09:02:22    134325  4885    #MB04   3.9         m             MVW                531861.22             8013605.37
29/04/2019  09:03:55    134325  4884    #MB04   28.57      °C             MVW                531861.22  8013605.37
29/04/2019  09:06:51    134325  4884    #MB04   28.57      °C             MVW                531861.22  8013605.37
29/04/2019  09:09:01    134325  4884    #MB04   28.57      °C             MVW                531861.22  8013605.37
29/04/2019  09:10:15    134325  4885    #MB04   4.2         m             MVW               531861.22   8013605.37
29/04/2019  09:11:22    134321  4894    #MB03   28.57      °C             PRN               532228.65   8013999.41
29/04/2019  09:14:06    134325  4885    #MB04   4.2         m             MVW               531861.22   8013605.37
29/04/2019  09:15:29    134325  4884    #MB04   28.57      °C             MVW              531861.22    8013605.37
```

Aqui estão uma pequena amostra dos meus dados, eu fiz um gráfico de frequência absoluta das detecções por dia com o script abaixo, mas, agora preciso fazer um gráfico de frequência relativa ou ponderada.
O gráfico de frequência absoluta fiz da seguinte forma:

`````
table(mycbon$Date)->det_day
as.data.frame(det_day)->det_day
names(det_day)<-c("Dates","Freq")
head(det_day)
det_day$Dates <- as.Date(det_day$Dates)
ggplot(det_day,aes(x=Dates,y=Freq)) +  geom_bar(stat="identity") +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle =1, vjust = 0.5)) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks= "1 month", date_labels = "%m-%y") + labs(x = "Período do monitoramento acústico", y = "Frequencia de detecção")````

dput(head(mycbon$Date, 30))
`````

Aqui me gera um gráfico de frequência absoluta das detecções dos indivíduos mas preciso de um gráfico com frequência relativa ou ponderada das detecções.

Obrigada.

Comment: Se só quer a frequência das datas pode por favor por a saída de `dput(head(mycbon$Date, 30))` na pergunta?

Comment: É **a saída** do comando `dput` que deve estar na pergunta, não o comando. Qual é **o resultado** de `dput(head(mycbon$Date, 30))`?

Answer (score 2):

O seguinte código transforma os valores do eixo dos y em percentagens.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(det_day, aes(x = Dates, y = 100*Freq/sum(Freq))) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%m-%y") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  labs(x = "Período do monitoramento acústico", y = "Frequencia de detecção") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```